# spring annotation for ParameterMethodNameResolver

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-annotations

I am using the following controller for a parameter-method resolution.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/customer")
public class CustomerController extends MultiActionController{

    @RequestMapping(params = "action=add")
    public ModelAndView add(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        return new ModelAndView("CustomerPage", "msg","add() method");

    }
....
....
}
```

However,this makes the url of the following format to work:

```
http://localhost:7001/begin-mvc/customer/?action=update
```

How do I get this to work for /customer/*.htm?action=.....

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do the following:

```
@Controller

@RequestMapping("/customer")
public class CustomerController extends MultiActionController{

    @RequestMapping(value="{myHtmFile:.*\\.htm}", params = "action=add")
    public ModelAndView add(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, @PathVariable String myHtmFile) throws Exception {

        return new ModelAndView("CustomerPage", "msg","add() method");

    }
....
....
}
```

This uses RegEx to match the pattern.  The regex may need some work, but that's the general idea.  As a bonus, I show how you can assign the variable using the @PathVariable.  If you don't want to do that, I think you can just include the regex in the `{}` and drop the @PathVariable.